# Cannot update WordPress General Settings Site Title and Tagline

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, title, theme-options, options

I have a WordPress 4.4.2 installation with no SEO plugins at all. The plugins that I do have activated are WooCommerce, WooCommerce Multilingual, and WPML.

I am unable to update the Site Title and Tagline on the General Settings page. If I try to save the changes, the old Site Title and Tagline continue to be displayed in the text boxes.

I manually changed the Site Title and Tagline in the wp_options table of the database using PHPMyAdmin. However, these manual changes are not reflected on the General Settings page or the front end of the site. The General Settings text boxes still show the old Site Title and Tagline.

I checked my error log but there's no errors. I changed theme but that still didn't solve it. I cleared my history and cleared all WooCommerce sessions & transients. Still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the `wp-config.php` file if you have those lines, `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` then change the value or delete them

Comment: I don't have those lines. I think I just found the issue. It was WPML String Translation plugin. I disabled it and then things went back to normal. The plugin had a record called Blog Title that was storing the old Site Title

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your `wp-config.php` and double check that you are using the correct database, as if you have changed the values within the wp_options table then they should definitely be reflected in the settings in the back-end of WordPress, whereas, updating from WordPress might not have been saving etc.

Sounds like a strange issue though.  Are the changes you make to the database still there after you go to another table and back?  Or do they not save into the database when using PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, the changes made to the wp_options table using PHPMyAdmin remain even if I go to another table and then back to the wp_options table. My wp-config.php file is using the correct database.

Comment: How odd... can you search the database for occurrences of the odd site title?  From my understanding if its right in `wp_options` it should be correct on the site unless there's been some core modification.  If the old site title remains and it's not in the database, then I would imagine it's hard coded in somehow.

Comment: I haven't hard coded the old site title and tagline. It's really strange.

Comment: Just found out that it was WPML String Translation plugin. I disabled it and then things went back to normal. The plugin had a record called Blog Title that was storing the old Site Title.

Comment: Brilliant, glad you got it sorted and hope I helped!